# Failure retrieving icon in package

Tags: android, exception

my Android app recently shows some strange behavior. The below included NullPointerException is thrown only on specific devices, for example a Motorola Defy device with Android 2.3.4 produces this Exception. Although it works fine on a Froyo 2.3.6 Nexus One and 2.2. HTC Desire, as well on Honeycomb tablet devices. The interesting thing is, I do not access the AppIcon myself anywhere in the code. Here is the Stack trace, thrown by the Motorola Defy:

```
W/PackageManager(14947): Failure retrieving icon 0x7f020004 in package com.a.project
W/PackageManager(14947): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/PackageManager(14947):    at android.app.ActivityThread$ResourcesKey.<init>(ActivityThread.java:1138)
W/PackageManager(14947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1207)
W/PackageManager(14947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1266)
W/PackageManager(14947):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ContextImpl.java:2439)
W/PackageManager(14947):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ContextImpl.java:2332)
W/PackageManager(14947):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:140)
W/PackageManager(14947):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationIcon(ContextImpl.java:2387)
W/PackageManager(14947):    at com.motorola.filemanager.utils.IconifiedText.buildIconItem(IconifiedText.java:287)
W/PackageManager(14947):    at com.motorola.filemanager.local.DirectoryScanner.run(DirectoryScanner.java:83)
```

After doing some research, I found the following article, leading to no concrete answer, what could be the cause of the problem:

 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9151

I made sure to set the following permission in the Manifest file:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

The only place, where I access the PackageManager in my code is for versionName retreival purposes:

```
try {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    return manager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does anybody have a clue what could cause this problem?

Best regards,
Mitja

Answer (score 2):

The null pointer exception is at

```
om.motorola.filemanager.utils.IconifiedText.buildIconItem(IconifiedText.java:287).
android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:140).
```

so I guess your project loaded the apk's icon in somewhere. Before `loadIcon` you should be add the following two lines:

```
pkg.applicationInfo.sourceDir = "apkpath";  //"apkpath" is your apk's absolute path
pkg.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = "apkpath";
```

Answer (score 0):

before where u return ....
add:
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager(context).getPackageInfo(                        context.getPackageName(), 0);
packageinfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir = mSavePath+"/"+APKNAME;//your apk absolute
packageinfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = mSavePath+"/"+APKNAME;//your apk absolute